# Corresponding file start downloading automatically after form submission

Tags: php, html, popup

Can anyone recommend the best solution for this?

I add Reveal popup on my wordpress site. In my website there a download page which contain 6 PDF file. I integrate popup with it, when anyone click on Download button of any PDF file popup appears automatically. Popup contain a subscription form with Name, Email Address, Address field.

Popup, Form everything works properly. I just need- Corresponding file(depends on which link clicked) start downloading automatically after form submission.

### HTML code

```
<div style="width:100%;">
   <div style="width:30%; float:left;">
        <h6>Top tips for Make Vs. Buy decisions</h6>
        <p>Make Vs. Buy (MvB) is an integral part of any purchasing function. We have to give information and help make decisions over the best strategic fit of our manufacturing operations whether in-house or in the supply chain. Here are some pointers to help you get it right.</p>
        <a href="pdffile1.pdf" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal"><img src="http://inxpresssheffield.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/document.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div style="width:30%; float:left;">
        <h6>Top tips for Make Vs. Buy decisions</h6>
        <p>Make Vs. Buy (MvB) is an integral part of any purchasing function. We have to give information and help make decisions over the best strategic fit of our manufacturing operations whether in-house or in the supply chain. Here are some pointers to help you get it right.</p>
        <a href="pdffile2.pdf" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal"><img src="http://inxpresssheffield.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/document.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div style="width:30%; float:right;">
        <h6>Top tips for Make Vs. Buy decisions</h6>
        <p>Make Vs. Buy (MvB) is an integral part of any purchasing function. We have to give information and help make decisions over the best strategic fit of our manufacturing operations whether in-house or in the supply chain. Here are some pointers to help you get it right.</p>
        <a href="pdffile3.pdf" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal"><img src="http://inxpresssheffield.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/document.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <h1>Thanks for clicking</h1><br />
    <p class="popup_text">In order to receive access to your document please complete the details below.</p>
    <p class="popup_text">From time to time we may send you information that we think will be relevant to your interests, however you can unsubscribe at any time by emailing UNSUBSCRIBE to <a href="mailto:enquiriesuk122@inxpress.com" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000; font-weight:bold;">enquiriesuk122@inxpress.com</a></p>
    <form method="post" action="http://inxpresssheffield.co.uk/popup/submit.php" style="display:block !important;">
        <span class="popup_label">Name:</span><span style="margin-left:76px;"><input type="text" name="name" class="popup_input" /></span><br />
        <span class="popup_label">Company Name:</span><span style="margin-left:10px;"><input type="text" name="company" class="popup_input" /></span><br />
        <span class="popup_label">Email Address:</span><span style="margin-left:20px;"><input type="text" name="email" class="popup_input" /></span><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
    </form>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

### PHP Code

```
<?php
   $to = "gamarsh@yahoo.co.uk";
   $subject = "Downloadable Documents";
   $message = "Hey, Someone Sent you a Contact Message via Download Section of your Website.Details below-Name: $_POST[name]Company Name: $_POST[company] Email Address: $_POST[email] IP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."";
   $from = "info@inxpresssheffield.co.uk";
   $headers = "From:" . $from;
   mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   header("location:http://inxpresssheffield.co.uk/downloads/");
?>
```

Comment: Please simplify your huge production code to a minimal example so get your point across. Currently this is not useful for anyone but yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can add something like an `<input type="hidden" name="thefile"/>` and you modify the value of this input with JavaScript when the user click the link?

You can get the value back with the `$_POST["thefile"]` in your PHP, so you can add it to your redirect (header()).

Note that you may use relative links instead of absolute in case your hostname change later.